# vertical scroll two tables at the same time

Tags: javascript

I have two tables that must scroll together:

```
$('.vscroll').on('scroll', function (e) {
    divTable1.scrollTop = e.scrollTop;
    divTable2.scrollTop = e.scrollTop;
```

There's a little lag issue though.  Table1 scrolls milliseconds before Table2.

I know scrollTop fires the scroll event, but is there a way to delay the scrolling of Table1 until Table2's scrollTop is also set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a setTimeout to trigger the scrolls, and then return false to cancel the original scrollevent:

```
var ignoreEvent = false;

$(".vscroll").on('scroll', function (e) {
    if (!ignoreEvent) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            ignoreEvent = true;
            table1.scrollTop = e.scrollTop;
            table2.scrolLTop = e.scrollTop;
        }, 100);
    }

    ignoreEvent = false;
    return false; // cancels the original scroll event.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had tried setting time out but it didn't work.  However, once I included the "returned false", it worked!!!

Answer (score 3):

I'm using `div`s instead of `table`s but you get the idea

```
$("div").on("scroll",function(){
    $("div:not(this)").scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
});
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/q7ycn/)

Comment: I should have been more explicit.  Those are div tags.