# How scroll two data frames simultaneously in R shiny dashboard

Tags: r, scroll, shiny, dt

I am currently working in data cleaning and visualization.
I though a useful feature would be to scroll two almost identical tables at the same time.
(The only change would be a column of the date time for example. )
So when you scroll the table in one side you can see the changes for the same row in the other side. 
I was looking in google, and I imagine maybe I have to use javascript. Anyway I am not working with rhandsometable
Does anybody knows how to perform this action?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `step 1 - ` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21562640/vertical-scroll-two-tables-at-the-same-time, `step 2 - `https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/packaging-javascript.html

Comment: If the tables are "join"-able, why not join them and only scroll one table?

Comment: Thank you @Pork Chop, working on that. About the comment of Valeri Voev, the idea is good as a fast solution. But it seems nicer (from my point of view) if the tables are separated. It is like more clear, and I can separate them even in different coloured boxes. Thanks anyway.

Comment: if anybody has a solution to share here that would be great. Even if I look at the links shared by @PorkChop I still don't know how to implement this.

Comment: @Angelo in the link that Pork Chop added, there is one comment that shows the implementation http://jsfiddle.net/q7ycn/. Basically, you have to pack the code as mentioned in the second link, in the paragraph *Inlined JavaScript file
* or *JavaScript file under www/
*. I have a code somewhere, I will try to upload it once I find it.

Comment: This worked for me with two side by side data tables.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66582335/dynamically-sized-sidebarpanel-and-mainpanel-in-shiny/66591242#66591242?newreg=7f02f895597d4f34acedf474aa98cd79