# Dynamically sized sidebarPanel and mainPanel in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a Shiny app that has dynamically generated UI input options in the sidebarPanel that generate plots in the mainPanel. In the actual code, sidebarPanel and mainPanel are significantly longer than most displays will allow. Because of this, I would like them to scroll independently while displaying the titlePanel at the top.

A minimal reproducible example is below. I've manually defined the max-height at 925 px. This works fine for browsers on 1080p, but on a 1440p display it looks a little silly as the max-height parameter makes the sidebar scroll at 925px still. If I set the max-height: 100%, the overflow doesn't work at all and only the main page scrolls. How can I get independently scrolling sidebarPanel and mainPanel that are dynamically sized to the browser window?

```
ui = fluidPage (
    titlePanel("Test Server"),
    sidebarLayout(position = "right",
        sidebarPanel(
            width = 2,
            style = paste0("overflow-y: scroll;
                            max-height: 925px;"),
            tags$html(tags$h1("This")),tags$html(tags$h1("is")),tags$html(tags$h1("dummy")),tags$html(tags$h1("content")),tags$html(tags$h1("to")),tags$html(tags$h1("force")),tags$html(tags$h1("the")),tags$html(tags$h1("page")),tags$html(tags$h1("to")),tags$html(tags$h1("scroll")),
            tags$html(tags$h1("This")),tags$html(tags$h1("is")),tags$html(tags$h1("dummy")),tags$html(tags$h1("content")),tags$html(tags$h1("to")),tags$html(tags$h1("force")),tags$html(tags$h1("the")),tags$html(tags$h1("page")),tags$html(tags$h1("to")),tags$html(tags$h1("scroll")),
        ),
        mainPanel(
            width = 10,
            style = paste0("overflow-y: scroll;
                            max-height: 925px;"),
            tags$html(tags$h1("This")),tags$html(tags$h1("is")),tags$html(tags$h1("dummy")),tags$html(tags$h1("content")),tags$html(tags$h1("to")),tags$html(tags$h1("force")),tags$html(tags$h1("the")),tags$html(tags$h1("page")),tags$html(tags$h1("to")),tags$html(tags$h1("scroll")),
            tags$html(tags$h1("This")),tags$html(tags$h1("is")),tags$html(tags$h1("dummy")),tags$html(tags$h1("content")),tags$html(tags$h1("to")),tags$html(tags$h1("force")),tags$html(tags$h1("the")),tags$html(tags$h1("page")),tags$html(tags$h1("to")),tags$html(tags$h1("scroll")),
        )
    )
)
server = function(input, output) { 
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

taken the idea from [here](https://spartanideas.msu.edu/2015/07/25/shiny-hack-vertical-scrollbar/) your code can be adjusted to achieve independent scrolling of the two panels!

Best regards,
Lea

```
ui = fluidPage (
  titlePanel("Test Server"),
  sidebarLayout(position = "right",
                sidebarPanel(
                  width = 2,
                  style = paste0("height: 90vh; overflow-y: auto;"), ##CHANGE
                  tags$html(tags$h1("This")),tags$html(tags$h1("is")),tags$html(tags$h1("dummy")),tags$html(tags$h1("content")),tags$html(tags$h1("to")),tags$html(tags$h1("force")),tags$html(tags$h1("the")),tags$html(tags$h1("page")),tags$html(tags$h1("to")),tags$html(tags$h1("scroll")),
                  tags$html(tags$h1("This")),tags$html(tags$h1("is")),tags$html(tags$h1("dummy")),tags$html(tags$h1("content")),tags$html(tags$h1("to")),tags$html(tags$h1("force")),tags$html(tags$h1("the")),tags$html(tags$h1("page")),tags$html(tags$h1("to")),tags$html(tags$h1("scroll")),
                ),
                mainPanel(
                  width = 10,
                  style = paste0("height: 90vh; overflow-y: auto;"),##CHANGE
                  tags$html(tags$h1("This")),tags$html(tags$h1("is")),tags$html(tags$h1("dummy")),tags$html(tags$h1("content")),tags$html(tags$h1("to")),tags$html(tags$h1("force")),tags$html(tags$h1("the")),tags$html(tags$h1("page")),tags$html(tags$h1("to")),tags$html(tags$h1("scroll")),
                  tags$html(tags$h1("This")),tags$html(tags$h1("is")),tags$html(tags$h1("dummy")),tags$html(tags$h1("content")),tags$html(tags$h1("to")),tags$html(tags$h1("force")),tags$html(tags$h1("the")),tags$html(tags$h1("page")),tags$html(tags$h1("to")),tags$html(tags$h1("scroll")),
                )
  )
)
server = function(input, output) { }
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm obviously not super familiar with CSS. I hadn't seen the vh unit before, that's exactly what I needed.